# Code Does Not Work WIth <!DOCTYPE html> at the top

Tags: javascript, html

I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of my page and what the page is suppose to do is allow the user to click anywhere on the page, and then redirect to another URL.

It works when I remove `<!DOCTYPE html` but I would like to keep it in the page

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
    BODY.enterPage{
      cursor:hand;
    }
</style>
<script>
  function goto(){
    location.href = "http://www.google.com"
  }
</script>
</head>

  <body class="enterPage" onclick="goto();">

  Your Content

</body>

</html>
```

why does this happen?

Comment: Having an HTML5 doctype *and* an xhtml `<html>` tag makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. *Especially* since you've got a `<meta>` tag that declares the content to be HTML also. Get rid of that `xmlns` attribute because it is an affont to all that is good and kitten-friendly.

Comment: You should probably just add `html, body { height: 100%; }` to your CSS

Comment: Or my new favorite `height: 100vh; width: 100vw;`

Comment: What @Pointy says makes no sense; see section 9 “The XHTML syntax” in W3C HTML5 PR.

Comment: Why do you want to keep `<!DOCTYPE html>`? Its only effect is that it puts browsers to “standards mode” when rendering the page, and the page has been designed to work in “quirks mode” (for those values of “work” that apply here at all).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela it makes no sense to use XHTML stuff in a document that's declared to be an HTML document with an HTML content type. It doesn't matter what the XHTML syntax says; browsers will interpret the content as plain HTML anyway.

Comment: @Pointy I have tried everything suggested, the only thing that works is removing the DOCTYPE still.. this will mainly be used on mobile devices, will the doctype be needed?

Comment: Well one problem I just noticed is that the value "hand" is invalid for the CSS "cursor" property. That should be "pointer". [Here is a jsbin with your code and a couple of minor CSS additions. That page uses an HTML doctype like yours.](http://jsbin.com/qikiyu/1)

Comment: Here's a simple and clear explanation of the DOCTYPE issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate @Pointy comments, additionally, do the following changes in your CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            body.enterPage {
                cursor: pointer;             //Not hand!
            }
            html, body {                     //Set document width/height to 100%
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function goto() {
                location.href = "http://www.google.com"
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="enterPage" onclick="goto();">
        Your Content
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: copied and pasted the whole code and didn't work for me, i need `hand` so i used that but still doesnt work

Comment: @JoeBobby the value "hand" is going to be ignored by all browsers other than IE. The value "pointer" will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Add height and width of the body to 100%. Most probably it might solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to fix the functional issue, making the entire area clickable, is to set

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

However, this still leaves small areas at the edges (a few pixels of margin), so if you really want the entire viewport to be clickable, add

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

The reason is that in “standards mode”, browsers by default make the `body` element just as tall as needed for its content (as you can see by setting a border on it). When the doctype string is missing, browsers operate in [“quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html)”, where strange things happen, including the imitation of old browsers in the sense of making `body` 100% tall by default. When you want this in “standards mode”, just say it, in CSS.

To make the pointer (badly named in CSS as `cursor`) look like a hand or similar icon on all browsers, add

```
body { cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; }
```

This handles both very old IE versions (which recognize `hand` but not `pointer`) and modern browsers, which implement [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) properly.